# Passing data into PartialView logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I was following a tutorial in a book on creating a categories side menu using a partial view.
It went fine until it got to the feature of showing the currently selected category.

The problem arises as **there doesn't seem to be any logic in passing the currently selected category to the partial view.**

The layout CSHTML file has for displaying categories

```
@{ 
    Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); 
  }
```

as you can see the selected category ID is not being passed

if you look at the NavController the menu method accepts a select category ID

```
  public PartialViewResult Menu(int selCatID = -1)
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedCatID = selCatID;
        return PartialView(repository.Categories);

    }
```

But the call from the layout.html file seems to be calling the Menu without a parameter causing the selCatID to always be -1

Here is the view for Menu

```
 @foreach (var cat in Model)
{
 @Html.RouteLink( cat.CategoryName , new {
controller = "Company", action="List"
       , catID=cat.ID, page= 1},
    new { @class = cat.ID == ViewBag.SelectedCatID ? "selected" : null }
)
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any visible code that shows the  selected CatID from the main controller (Company) being passed into the view for NavController.

I figured that the main controller should be setting the viewbag for the selected ID.I did the following changed, and it worked but I am not sure if it is the correct technique. **I was wondering if I am doing it correctly or have I missed out something?.**

in the layout file pass a parameter in:

```
Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav", new { selCatID = ViewBag.SelCatID });
```

in the main entity controller (CompanyController) set the viewbag of the current selected ID

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    .....
 public ViewResult List(int catID = -1, int page = 1)
      {
       CompaniesListViewModel viewModel = new CompaniesListViewModel
        {
         ...........
        };

        ViewBag.SelectedCatID = catID;
        return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Why is the Action receiving catID as -1?

Comment: TravisJ i fixed the typo when entering here, the book was using this formatting, I usually avoid using it, for this very reason. 

Andre - the -1 is there so catID is an optional parameter, -1 indicates no category was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems was this code

```
  Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav", new { selCatID = ViewBag.SelCatID });
```

I had added the parameter in as without it was passing in a null value and crashing it on the first run. So I changed it back to:
      Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav");

To handle the null, I changed the parameter to a nullable int

```
    public PartialViewResult Menu(int? selCatID = -1)
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedCatID = selCatID;
```

And now all is working.